# Add rows to table with jQuery .each and .append

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add rows to a table. GetLogEntries returns an IEnumererable of an anonymous type.  How to I refer to the members? When I append the constant string, the correct number of rows is written, but when I try to refer to an element in the anonymous type, nothing it written.  How to I refer to the members of the anonymous type?

```
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetLogEntries")', { FacilityID: selectedFacility }, function (entries) {
            if (entries != null && !jQuery.isEmptyObject(entries)) {
                var logEntries = $('#logEntries');
                $.each(entries, function (index, entry) {
                    //logEntries.append($("<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>"));
                    logEntries.append($("<tr><td>",entry.InventoryID,"</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>"));
                });
            };
        });
```

Comment: Your append is weird.  You are giving it the result of a `$()` with three arguments, not one single string.  Did you typo a comma in place of a `+` concatenator?

Comment: `$("<tr><td>",entry.InventoryID,"</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>")` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Taplar [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) takes an infinite amount of elements, however the `$( ... )` certainly doesn't make sense.

Comment: .append in this case only gets one argument, i think taplar mispoke

Comment: @Taplar & Kevin B -  Yup, think we're all on the same page here. Clarified my comment.

Comment: Yeah, my fingers glazed over as I was typing that originally.  It should also be noted that the `$()` is unnecessary.  HTML added with `append()` will be parsed anyway.  No need to stick it in a `$()`

Comment: Thanks!  I got rid of the extra $() and changed the commas to plus signs. It works.  I'm new to jQuery, still in the cut and paste stage.